# Evaluate $\int_0^\pi \exp(-b\cos x)dx $

Tags: calculus

I found the solution of $\int \exp(\cos x)dx $ to be $K_0(x)$ [Modified Bessel function], but could not find the solution for $\int_0^\pi \exp(-b\cos x)dx $.

Comment: Try $-b\cos(x)=y$ and use [these integral representations](https://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselK/07/01/01/) by having a different number than $0$

Comment: Mathematica gives $\int_{0}^{\pi} \exp (-b \cos (x)) \, dx = \pi I_0 (b)$ where $I_0$ is the Bessel $I$ function.

Comment: See [$(10.32.1)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32.E1) in the DLMF.

Comment: Note also that $\int \exp(\cos x)dx \neq K_0(x)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tl;dr as stated by [@KStarGamer](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/885224/kstargamer)

> Mathematica gives $\int_0^\pi\exp(-b\cos(x))\mathrm{d}x=\pi I_0(b)$ where $I_0$ is the Bessel $I$ function.

**Proof if you want to check**

If you start with the sum definition of the exponential function
$$
e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}
$$
you can change the integral into a sum of an easier integral
$$
\int_0^\pi\exp(-b\cos(x))\mathrm{d}x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}\int_0^\pi(-b\cos(x))^n\mathrm{d}x
$$
To make life easier, we can actually split the integral up into two integrals over the range $[0,\pi/2]$ (from this point I'll mostly just be writing the integral and incorporate it back into the sum later)
$$
\int_0^\pi(-b\cos(x))^n\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(b\cos(x))^n+(-b\cos(x))^n\mathrm{d}x
$$
You can prove this by seeing that $\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)=-\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+x\right)$ or by looking at a graph.

If we now take out the constants and factorise we are left with
$$
b^n\left[\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^n(x)\mathrm{d}x+(-1)^n\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^n(x)\mathrm{d}x\right]
$$
The integrals here are called [Wallis' integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis%27_integrals) (denoted $W_n$)If we put this backk into the sum we get
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{b^n}{n!}\cdot W_n(1+(-1)^n)
$$

When $n$ is odd, $1+(-1)^n=0$, so we can discard these terms of the sum leaving us with
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{2b^{2n}W_{2n}}{(2n)!}
$$
The Wallis' integrals have a specific solution for odd and even values of $n$
$$
W_{2n}=\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}(n!)^2}\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}
$$
which gives us
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\pi b^{2n}}{2^{2n}(n!)^2}
$$
Taking out constants and factorising gives
$$
\pi\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(n!)^2}\left(\frac{b}{2}\right)^{2n}
$$
which by [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I%CE%B1,_K%CE%B1) is
$$
\pi I_0(b)
$$

Comment: Please, avoid answering low quality question, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards)